# "Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted."

Tags: ruby, hash, enumeration

From the ruby documentation at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-each :

> Hashes enumerate their values in the order that the corresponding keys were inserted.

Regularly, I would expect to enumerate hashes (in any arbitrary language) in random order.

How does ruby manage to track the order of insertion? Does it keep a linked list between keys in addition to the hash buckets? I guess that would be pretty straightforward, but I'm really surprised (in a good way) that they did it in the first place.

Comment: https://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/

Comment: That is an implementation detail, and I guess that depends on the Ruby implementation.

Comment: @sawa no, it isn't, that's why the docs don't say it's an implementation detail. Any post 1.9 ruby would have these, it's a change in the contract of the class.

Comment: I am not saying that the ordered hash in an implementation detail. I am saying that the way Ruby "manages to the order" (what you asked) is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it keeps a linked list. This can be done without compromising the typical O(1) amortized worst-case step complexity guarantees of a typical hash table, since all the operations that make linked lists expensive (e.g. deleting an element) are related to needing to traverse the list in order to *find* an element, but in this special case, the "finding" part can be short-circuited by using hash table lookup.

If you are interested in the internals of Ruby implementations, I recommend reading the Rubinius source code; it is much cleaner and easier to read than YARV, plus, it is written in Ruby, a language you presumable already know by heart. Rubinius's `Hash` class is implemented in [`core/hash.rb`](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/hash.rb). Note that current versions of Rubinius use a [*Hash Array Mapped Trie (HAMT)*](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie), which is significantly different from the simple traditional hash table that YARV uses, but that has no bearing on the use of the additional linked list. And if you really want to, you can look at an [older version](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/a8f23c1acf1eada25ecc6a46dadac80f6aab5e63/core/hash.rb) that still has the traditional hash table.

Answer (score 1):

This [forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/166075) has the exact answer you are looking for and it is answered by Matz himself.

> *Could anybody explain why this feature was added?*
>
> Useful for some cases, especially for keyword arguments.
>
> *Isn't it going to slow down the operations on the Hash?*
>
> No. hash reference operation does not touch order information, only
>   for iteration.  Memory consumption increased a bit.

Comment: The "exact answer" should be about "how?", not "why?".